# How to install a hanging chair in concrete ceiling so it's removable?

Tags: concrete, ceiling, hanging

I would like to install a hanging chair or two in a concrete ceiling in such a way that I can eventually remove it. What's the best way to make sure the mount is strong, safe, and can still be removed (not necessarily reinstalled)? The space is a rental so I'll have to remove and patch the concrete holes when I move out.

### Specs

Ceiling is 6" rebar-reinforced concrete (residential)
Allowed to drill holes up to 1/4" wide and 3" deep
Supported weight should be at least 600 Lbs
Prefer to use 4-hole plates rather than single bolt hooks

#### Option A

I was originally thinking of installing a [square u-shaped eye plate](https://www.google.com/search?q=u-shaped+eye+plate) like these using Tapcon screws. Concerns with this are:

- concrete might crack under load if the screws are too close
- concrete might crumble if shear force is applied to the screws repeatedly over time (e.g. chair swinging)

#### Option B

It's been suggested I install threaded bolts secured with epoxy and then cut them flush with the ceiling when moving out. (Not my preferred method.)

What are other options?
If I were to use wedge/sleeve anchors, would I want to use epoxy with them?
Would two or three-hold plates also be sufficient? It looks like 1/4" diam. 1 3/4" length [Tapcon screw anchors](https://www.tapcon.com/getattachment/a7f32fe2-3c0a-48ce-a587-b5606e67e32f/charts-performancetables-bluewhitestainless-v0-1-c) can provide more than enough tensile and shear strength if installed at the minimum 2" distance from each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use method a) but use ankers instead, and if you and concerned about the bolts being too close to could anker a wood plate instead and then bolt the swing eye to the wood plate or steel plate so you have the bolts spaced (you could put more than 4 using this way if you are concerned about them giving way)

Comment: Don't hesitate to post an answer if you've done your project, so other users (me) can learn from your approach :). Thank you !

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă - I haven't yet but will post here if I do. Thanks for reminding me.